# Java value plus variable++

Tags: java, operators, increment

Consider the following code

```
int val1 = 3;
val1++;
int val2 = val1++;
System.out.println(val1);
System.out.println(val2);
```

**Val1 value = 5;
Val2 value = 4;**

*Why is the value of Val1 "5"?*

As I understand it it should be 4, because:
at line1 it is assigned value of 3, on line2 1 gets added by way of val1++ which result in val1 being 4.

Val2 is the value of val1 thus 4, plus 1 which is 5

HOwever the compiler gives val1 a value of 5 and val2 a value of 4, what am I not understanding or missing here?

I realize val1++ is used a second time but it is assigned to val2, and should not effect val1s value, or am I wrong?

Comment: If you have an answer that's better than the current ones please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`a++` is known as postfix.

add `1` to `a`, returns the old value.

`++a` is known as prefix.

add `1` to `a`, returns the new value.

so `int val2 = val1++;` will return the old Value **(4)**

and still add **one to val1**

Answer (score 1):

Because the postfix increment operator add one to the `val1` after the assignment to `val2`, if you want to have `val2` equal to 5 too you should use :

```
int val2 = ++val1;
```

A postfix expression followed by a ++ operator is a postfix increment expression.  **The value of the postfix increment expression is the value of the variable BEFORE the new value is stored(incremented).**

To recap :

**Post Increment**(`val++`) : First execute the statement then increase the value by one.
**Pre Increment** (`++val`) : First increase the value by one then execute the statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can increment a variable by

```
val1++
```

or by using

```
++val1
```

The first option performs the assigment first and increments val1 afterwards. Long version:

```
val2 = val1;
val1 = val1 + 1;
```

The 2nd option performs the increment first and assigns then the new value to val2. Long version of this behaviour:

```
val1 = val1 + 1;
val2 = val1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`++` operator aworks in 2 phases:

- returns current value of `val1`
- add 1 to `val1`

So in your scenario, you first add 1 to val1 (but you don't print it)
Secondly you assign to `val2` value of val1, but after assigning it's value operator ++ adds 1 to `val1`.

As for your update question: When you are assigning `val1++` to a variable, you are first copying value from val1, then assigning it to `val2`, and thirdly incrementing val1. That is why you have such result. Integers as well as primitives are copied by value, not reference, so change to `val1` will not afect `val2`.

For better understanding it, try to replace `val1++` with `++val1`. In this way you will first increment value, and then return it, then you should have `val1==val2==5`

Answer (score 0):

Basically,

```
int val2 = val1++;
```

has the same effect as:

```
int val2 = val1;
val1++;
```

Answer (score 0):

`val++` is **post-increment operation**.

In post-increment/decrement operation a value is **assigned first then it is incremented/decremented**.

So, `y = x++` is equivalent to 
`y = x`
`x=x+1`

In your case, `val2` is assigned **old value** of `val1` and the `val1` is incremented, which gives output as 
**Val2 = 4**
**Val1=5**

Answer (score 0):

Its simple:

int val2 = val1++; <--- this statement works like this

**Step 1**: int val2 is initialized

**Step 2**: val1's value is assigned to val2

**Step 3**: value of val1 is incremented by 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
int val1 = 3; here val1=3
val1++;       here val1=4
int val2 = val1++;
and thus val1 becomes 5 and val2 also becomes 5 because before you assign value to val2 you increment as val1++
```

Answer (score 0):

The `val++` is a Postfix Increment operation, which **produces the original pure value stored in the variable before it is incremented.**

You can take a look at **[Increment/Decrement Operators](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java/langref/ch04_03.htm)** for further information.

In your case :

```
int val2 = val1++;
```

Will set the value of `val1` to `val2` before incrementing it, that's why you got `4` as value in `val2` and `5` in `val1`.

**Note:**

And if you don't want your operation to affect `val1` value , you should have done this:

```
int val2 = val1+1;
```