# Java how to find positive divisors of a given number

Tags: java

How do I make this to display the positive divisors of any number? What am I missing? Any help would be great. Thank you!

```
public static void homework4(int value){
    if(value > 0){
        int count = 1;
        while(count <= 12){
            if(12%count==0){
                System.out.println(count);
            }
            count=count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current attempt? Does it not compile? Does it throw exceptions? Give the wrong result? Please explain the details.

Comment: And give some examples. If you want people to help you - start by showing some effort in asking properly!

Comment: What you're missing is the concept that **we don't do people's homework here**.  [An open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems).

Comment: it does not compile.

Comment: If there is a compile error that you do not understand, then you need to [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Why are you using 12 if you want positive divisors of any number? Should it not be `value`

Comment: OP - take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069410/java-value-plus-variable) to understand why your `count` wasn't updating

Answer (score 1):

`count ++` already update the value of count, you don't have to do `count = count++`. (`count ++;` is equivalent to `count = count + 1;` ).
But maybe something else is wrong, can you put what error you obtain if that's not enough ?

Comment: yup. good eye. Just started writing that myself. That is the problem. `count = count++` will leave it 0 all the time.